# Why is this memory leaking?

Tags: flutter

In this example, each time I press "Click", 50M of ram is allocated. It is never reclaimed, I can push 30 pages and take up 1.5gb, despite there only ever being 1 page on the nav stack. GC never kicks in. What's going on here?

`Flutter (Channel master, 2.1.0-11.0.pre.122, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.1440], locale en-US)`

```
void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: MemoryTest(),
  ));
}

class MemoryTest extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<EdgeInsets> insets = List.generate(
    1000000,
    (index) => EdgeInsets.all(0),
  );
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.white,
      child: Column(
        children: [
          OutlinedButton(
            child: Text("CLICK"),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (_) => MemoryTest(),
              ));
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: What's the purpose of this test?

Comment: To understand how memory allocation (and collection) works over the lifetime of a Flutter App. 

Specifically I want to confirm whether objects like EdgeInsets used inside a given view are reclaimed by GC once that view is destroyed.

Comment: That's a very good observation ! After a few tests, the only way I found to clean the memory allocation without calling the GC manually, is to use a StatefulWidget and to clear the huge list in the dispose() method. I'll do more tests to understand how it's working

Comment: It seems like it's a legit bug in the framework, I've created an issue here which is getting some attention: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/79605

Comment: what about trigger gc manually?

Comment: great finding..

Comment: Just a waste of a perfectly good bounty! :'(

Answer (score 1):

The answer here is twofold. On one hand, its a bug, and the flutter team is working on it: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/79605

The actual cause for the bug here seems to actually be the closure, wrapping context which is forcing the stateless widget to stay in memory forever.

If you avoid the context in the closure, by caching the navigator as a local var, the leak doesnt happen. Obviously most Flutter devs are not doing this, and many code examples directly from Flutter also do this, so hopefully the team can fix this.

Answer (score -1):

U should move ListItem inside the function build

```
class MemoryTest extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  final insets = List.generate(
    1000000,
    (index) => EdgeInsets.all(0),
  );
    return Container(
      color: Colors.white,
      child: Column(
        children: [
          OutlinedButton(
            child: Text("CLICK"),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (_) => MemoryTest(),
              ));
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```